# Does every little event published to an Event Aggregator need to be an empty CompositePresentationEvent of its own?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, design-patterns, prism

I am trying to understanding the *Event Aggregator pattern* from an architecture and design view point. I have never used Prism in WPF before, but I'm studying how it works on MSDN.

It seems to me that for every event, the user has to create a new event object that extends the `CompositePresentationEvent`. It also appears that the new event object has no functionality other than those it inherited from (it usually has no code for itself).

So for example:

A  `AddNewStuffEvent` would look like:

```
public class AddNewStuffEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<Object> {} //The end of the class
```

For a `HealthChangeEvent`:

```
public class HealthChangeEvent: CompositePresentationEvent<Object> {} //The end of the class
```

For a `BookFlipEvent`:

```
public class BookFlipEvent: CompositePresentationEvent<Object> {} //The end of the class
```

For a `BookCloseEvent`:

```
public class BookCloseEvent: CompositePresentationEvent<Object> {} //The end of the class
```

And this can go on forever for every little small event for `BookOpenEvent`, `BookTearEvent`, etc. So, in a particular namespace folder, there will be a whole ton of event classes, and the Event Aggregator is going to be loaded with all these event objects during runtime. That's, every little small event needs an empty class? Is this how it works? What could be a better way for this?

Comment: @dbaseman is right, but I also agree with you that it seems a bit awkward. Not because you need to create dozens of tiny classes - I don't mind that at all - but because it's using a *type* as a *name*, rather than as a real type. It's bending the language a bit in order to achieve strong typing. Still better than the alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every event type needs its own class, which you have to define.

> It also appears that the new event object has no functionality other than those it inherited from

The purpose is simply to provide strong typing for the event.  This makes it easier to write code to subscribe to them.  Ie, the subscribing code can be written like:

```
aggregator.GetEvent<AddNewStuffEvent>().Subscribe(Handler);
```

This is a preferable approach to alternatives, such as reliance on "magic strings" in the form of say `aggregator.GetEvent("AddNewStuffEvent").Subscribe(Handler)` (which could not be verified at compile time.

Comment: Thanks. But wouldn't this be a terror if suppose I intend to use this Event Aggregator for data binding purposes? I'm likely going to create a class for every property change event. Woah!

Comment: @xEnOn maybe I'm missing something, but why would you need to do that?    `RaisePropertyChanged` can still be one event, you don't need a separate class for each property, right?

Comment: I am not exactly using WPF in my work. I am learning the architecture design used in Prism, and then borrow ideas from it to create my own. My intention is to first create an Event Aggregator, and then base on this Event Aggregator, I create another layer of data binding mechanism on top of it. So, if the Event Aggregator has to have a single event class for every event, my concern is it may be unconvenient when I have many property change events.

Comment: @xEnOn ah, gotcha.  Yes, the idea of creating a new class for every single property is clearly untenable.